Proof that $\ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf X\mathbf Y^{-1}) = \ln \det (\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{-1/2}\mathbf X \mathbf Y^{-1/2})$
How do we prove that
\begin{equation}
\ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf X\mathbf Y^{-1}) = \ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{-1/2}\mathbf X \mathbf Y^{-1/2}).
\end{equation}
Here $\mathbf I$ is the identity matrix. If the above relation does not hold in general, could you state the conditions under which the relation is true?
My attempt:
\begin{align}
\ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf X\mathbf Y^{-1}) = & \ \ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf X \mathbf Y^{-1/2} \mathbf Y^{-1/2}) \\
= & \ \ln \det(\mathbf I + \mathbf Y^{+1/2} \mathbf Y^{-1/2} \mathbf X \mathbf Y^{-1/2} \mathbf Y^{-1/2}).
\end{align}
I am not sure about the next steps. Any leads will be much appreciated.

If $\mathbf{Y}$ is symmetric positive definite,
$$\begin{align}
&\det\left(\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{XY}^{-1}\right)\\
=&\det\left( \left\lbrace \mathbf{Y}^{1/2}+\mathbf{XY}^{-1/2}\right\rbrace \mathbf{Y}^{-1/2} \right)\\
=&\det\left( \mathbf{Y}^{1/2}+\mathbf{XY}^{-1/2}\right)\det\left( \mathbf{Y}^{-1/2} \right)
=\det\left( \mathbf{Y}^{-1/2} \right)\det\left( \mathbf{Y}^{1/2}+\mathbf{XY}^{-1/2}\right)\\
=&\det\left( \mathbf{Y}^{-1/2} \left\lbrace \mathbf{Y}^{1/2}+\mathbf{XY}^{-1/2}\right\rbrace  \right)\\
=&\det\left(\mathbf{I}+ \mathbf{Y}^{-1/2} \mathbf{XY}^{-1/2} \right)
\end{align}
$$
